# Normal convergence: $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1 + (n-1)x)(1 + nx)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

I want to prove that:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1 + (n-1)x)(1 + nx)}$$

is not normally convergent on $[a, \infty)$ for fixed $a>0$.

Let $U_n(x)$ denote the general term.

We have:

$$||U_n||_{\infty} = \sup_{x \ge a} \left( \frac{x}{(1 + (n-1)x)(1 + nx)} \right) \ge \sup_{x \ge a} \left( \frac{x}{(1 + (n-1)a)(1 + na)} \right) \ge \sup_{x \ge a} \left( \frac{x}{(1 + na)^2} \right) \ge \frac{1}{(1 + a)^2} \sup_{x \ge a} \left( \frac{x}{n^2} \right) \ge \frac{1}{(1+ a)^2} \times \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{(1+a)^2} \frac{1}{n} = a_n$$

The series of general term $a_n$ is divergent, so by comparison test the series of norms is divergent.

Can someone check/criticize my work? Thanks.

Bonus question: what are the sets on which we have normal convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first inequality is invalid, if you make the (positive) denominator smaller, since the numerator is also positive, you make the fraction larger.

Actually, the series is normally convergent on $[a,+\infty)$ for all $a > 0$, since for $n \geqslant 2$

$$0 < U_n(x) = \frac{x}{(1+(n-1)x)(1+nx)} < \frac{x}{(n-1)xnx} = \frac{1}{n(n-1)x} \leqslant \frac{1}{n(n-1)a},$$

and

$$0 < U_1(x) = \frac{x}{1+x} < 1.$$

The series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ is convergent, so

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lVert U_n\rVert_\infty \leqslant 1 + \frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)} = 1+\frac{1}{a} < +\infty.$$

If there is a problem, it occurs at $0$. For $n \geqslant 2$, we compute

$$U_n'(x) = \frac{(1+(n-1)x)(1+nx) - x[(n-1)(1+nx) + n(1+(n-1)x)]}{[(1+(n-1)x)(1+nx)]^2}$$

and to locate the maximum solve

\begin{align}
&&(1+(n-1)x)(1+nx) &= x[2n-1 + 2n(n-1)x]\\
&\iff& 1 + (2n-1)x + n(n-1)x^2 &= (2n-1)x + 2n(n-1)x^2\\
&\iff& 1 &= n(n-1)x^2\\
&\iff& \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}} &= x,
\end{align}

where the last is an equivalence since we only consider $x \geqslant 0$. Thus

\begin{align}
\lVert U_n\rVert_\infty &= U_n \biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}\biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{\Bigl(1 + \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}\Bigr)\Bigl(1 + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}\Bigr)\sqrt{n(n-1)}}\\
&= \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n-1})(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n})}\\
&= \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1})^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2n-1 + 2\sqrt{n(n-1)}}.
\end{align}

Since $\lVert U_n\rVert_\infty > \frac{1}{4n}$, we see that the series is not normally convergent on all of $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I can't believe I actually wrote down that first inequality; what a mess!